# Modifying a variable via events in node - is it safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine this scenario in node:

```
var output = '';

module1.on('done', function() {
    output += 'aaaa';
});

module2.on('done', function() {
    output += 'bbbb';
});

// ...Doing stuff...

// Assume this is inside a promise/callback and executed after both events have fired
console.log(output);
```

Is it possible to ever get output like `aabbaabb`?

Comment: thread-safe by default, because javascript is called by 1 thread. Now let's think about webworker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Similar states  can occur as a result of [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example) in concurrent environments, but Javascript execution in Node is inherently single-threaded. The methods will execute atomically.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153492/models-of-concurrency-in-nodejs) has some excellent relevant answers

Having said that, strings are immutable (and therefore inherently thread safe) in most languages so interleaved strings like your example should be impossible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `promises` to wait until every module will finish
   F.e. http://howtonode.org/promises
2. In every module fill variable by speecified order like (just an idea without promises):

   ```
   var output = ['',''];

   module1.on('done', function() {
       output[0] = 'aaaa';
   });

   module2.on('done', function() {
       output[1] = 'bbbb';
   });

   // ...Doing stuff...

   console.log(output.join(''));
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Regarding [1], the modules need to run in parallel, I should have clarified that.