# Has Node.js Abstarcted that multithreading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Hey Guys ,
              I am new to Node.js and have a doubt to clear ...

My question is when node js is single threaded and non blocking tel me about this scenario.
 Like When client1  sends a request to get the data from DB to the main thread of Node , Node assigns the task to the thread pool and say the T1 thread from the thread pool will be executing that task by accessing the data from DB.... Lets at the same time another client say client2  requests some data from DB to the main thread and node assigns that task also to the thread pool so say T2 also goes to the same DB  to get  the  data but still T1 has not finished accessing data from DB .. So  T2 is basically WAITING right ?  N guys also share some good videos and documents on Node.js and basic programming examples..

Thanks

Comment: "Your" js code runs in a single thread - but behind the scenes, blocking operations (such as socket/file access) are run in worker threads instead.  It's not multithreading in the sense that your node.js code can be executing in two contexts/code-paths simultaneously, but for I/O bound operations (e.g. most web servers), it appears in any practical sense to be heavily multithreaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no thread pool in JavaScript. Why would you expect one in a NodeJS environment, which is little more than V8?

Concurrency (not multithreading) is done by way of an event loop, not threads. In your example, if you do not have a connection pool to your DB, yes, T2 will wait for T1 to be finished **with the DB connection**. There is still no element of threading, the limit is that your DB connection can most likely not be multiplexing queries.

Comment: So how is node js  handling multiple client requests at a time. N are there no worker threads too ?

Comment: @SyedAmmarMustafa: Lack of threading doesn't mean every operation is blocking. Most operations on any V8-driven interpreter are non-blocking, and the entire operation cycle is event-driven. Some nice reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5177773/2167834