# Cannot migrate models not attached to this datasource

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I tried to create tables from models using code in server.js:

```
app.datasources['Billing'].automigrate(['Roles', 'Users'], function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

and got the following error:

```
[Error: Cannot migrate models not attached to this datasource: Roles Users ]
```

Indeed I'm not sure which way node creates tables in mysql db but this solution was provided in manual.

Probably someone has a link to any documentation regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like error message suggests, your models are not attached to "Billing" datasource. Use attachTo() to assign datasource to a model.

```
app.models.YourModel.attachTo(app.dataSources.Billing);
```

Also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173302/how-to-configure-two-different-datasource-for-a-model-in-strongloop-loopback-fra/31207946#31207946) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the file located in ***YourProject/server/boot/model-config.json*** and change the dataSource of the model you're using from "db" to the connector you're using.

eg:

```
Document": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
}
```

to

```
Document": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDs",
    "public": true
}
```

where mongoDs is my connector for MongoDB